# Setting new security token on logout in Symfony2

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

I'm using Symfony 2.4 with FOSUserBundle.

Admin user has ability to switch his security token to one for any other user, so he can log on any account in the system. I've did it with following code:

```
$newToken = new MyOwnToken($adminId, $user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($newToken);
```

MyOwnToken extends regular UsernamePasswordToken, holding additional adminId field (for reference to original admins account).

When admin logout of regular users account, security token is unset and he is redirected to the login page. I would like to change it a bit: instead of logging out, I'd like admin to get log back in his administrative account.

My question is: what do I need to prevent logging out if some of conditions are met (like current token is instance of MyOwnToken), and switch token to another instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different approach all together. It is called 'impersonating' users and described in documentation here - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html